Codeium in VS Code - auto focus pane after CMD I
for the codeium extension: Codeium.codeium (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Codeium.codeium), when I press CMD I on Mac, the focus is not automatically switched to the chat popup. This means I then need to manually click the popup. How can I change it so that focus is automatically switched?
Codeium doesn't provide much documentation.


Sometimes questions like these are better suited for the support team of the company than for StackOverflow, since they're the ones who need to fix it. It also looks like they have a discord (yuck!) but it might be worth checking to see if there's answers there.

I'd suggest to open a support request, and add a link here to your support request. This sounds like a bug to me. in the meantime, please add version info of your extension and VS Code installation to your question post.

This is a VSCode bug. I had the same problem on VSCode v1.90.*.
It was fixed in newer releases, just update your VSCode to latest version (1.92.2 at the moment of writing this post). This fixed issue for me.
